# How to apply color to selected text in a powerpoint addin?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I would like to apply a color to the user current selection in a powerpoint addin. 
In word, this function works :

```
    await Word.run(async context => {
        const selection = context.document.getSelection();
        await context.sync();
        selection.font.highlightColor = color;

        return context.sync();
    });
```

Basically, I just want to do the same thing in powerpoint but I don't even find a Powerpoint.run()... I guess I'm missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: Office JS API support for PowerPoint is (still) very limited. Mainly, only the original "shared" APIs can be used. You might want to upvote or post on UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33200554-powerpoint-api